# Protege Owl API DB to OWL

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, owl-api

I need to create OWL class from the first table name if cardinality 1:1 and OWL class from the second table name. If cardinality 1:* and one of tables describes object properties, create OWL object property from the first table name, than create OWL class from the second table name. How can I create OWL class from column name and do the rest? I have Protege OWL API installed in Eclipse.

```
package snippet;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import edu.stanford.smi.protege.exception.OntologyLoadException;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLModel;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLNamedClass;

public class Snippet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws OntologyLoadException {
    //-Dprotege.dir=

    //  SQL Server DB with JDBC
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1433";
     String userName = "xxx";
     String password = "xxx";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
        Statement smt = con.createStatement();
        smt.executeQuery("SELECT * from table_references");
        ResultSet rs = smt.getResultSet();

        while (rs.next()) { 
            String column1 = rs.getString("referenced_object_id");
            String column2 = rs.getString("name");
            String column3 = rs.getString("parent_column_id");
            String column4 = rs.getString("referenced_column_id");

            System.out.println(column1 + " | " + column2 + " | " + column3 + " | " + column4);
        }   

    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Protege API   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an OWLEntity and then add that to your manager. Something like:

```
String axiom=ontoIRI+"#"+input;

        //convert String into OWLAxiom
        OWLEntity entity=factory.getOWLEntity(EntityType.CLASS,IRI.create(axiom));

        //executing addition
        OWLDeclarationAxiom tempAxiom= factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(entity) ;

        // Add the axiom to our ontology
        AddAxiom addAx = new AddAxiom(tempOnto, tempAxiom);
        tempManager.applyChange(addAx);
```

This will only allow you to add a modelling element to your ontology. Each modelling element can have appropriate restrictions added. Follow the same AddAxiom syntax to add restrictions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about axioms. I done like that:

```
     OWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModel();
        while (rs.next()) { 
            String column1 = rs.getString("referenced_object_id");
            String column2 = rs.getString("name");
            String column3 = rs.getString("parent_column_id");
            String column4 = rs.getString("referenced_column_id");

            System.out.println(column1 + " | " + column2 + " | " +    column3 + " | " + column4);

            String sql = "SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE object_id='" + column1 + "'";

            if(column2.startsWith("op_")) {

                // create object property,class and point if its domain or range class
                //Now gettin error,that Object property already exist. Need to do something, I don't know what. 
               // if(owlModel.getJenaModel().contains(column2))  maybe

                OWLObjectProperty Property = owlModel.createOWLObjectProperty(column2);

            } else {
                // create class
                OWLNamedClass clas = owlModel.createOWLNamedClass(column2);
            }
```

[sreen] (http://postimg.org/image/m8vbeer7h/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Jena API which is not as good as OWL API for modifying an ontology. In your original question, you mention the use of OWL API. I would suggest you taking a look at it, it is way more easy: [OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Sorry, for not mentioning. I'm using ProtegeOWL_API. I have bove protege3.5 and protege4.2.

Comment: I think you better switch to the original OWL API. My experience is that if you don't want to write a plugin for protege, OWL API works like a charm.